# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown when writing data to excel

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to write about 200000 lines into Excel and getting the error

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

My code is like below:

```
DataTable dtS = new DataTable();

dtS = myFucntion();

FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/Tss_rpt.xlsx"),
                               FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook PBLXSSFWorkbook2 = 
    new NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook(fs);

XSSFSheet PBLsheet2 = (XSSFSheet)PBLXSSFWorkbook2.GetSheet("TssAML");

if (dtS.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    XSSFRow PBLrows;

    for (int i = 0; i < dtS.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        PBLrows = (XSSFRow)PBLsheet2.CreateRow(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < dtS.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            PBLrows.CreateCell(j).SetCellValue(dtS.Rows[i][j].ToString());
        }
    }

    PBLrows = null;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    PBLXSSFWorkbook2.Write(ms);
    ExportDataTableToExcel(ms, "Txn_Aml_rpt.xlsx");
}
else 
{ 
    clsMessageBox.Show("No Record(s) Found !!"); return; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
```

before writing data.

Comment: Why should he do it?

Comment: add some details to your answer please.